# Why can't I filter my row column with WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have this code I came up with to add a row column, however, when I try to filter by that Row column, it says Invalid column name for 'Row'.  If I remove the WHERE clause at the bottom, the code runs as expected.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.JobNo) AS [Row],
    a.JobNo,
    a.PartNo,
    a.WorkCntr,
    a.StepNo
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 r.JobNo,
                             r.PartNo,
                             r.WorkCntr,
                             r.StepNo
    FROM OrderRouting r 
    RIGHT JOIN Scheduling s ON r.JobNo = s.JobNo
    WHERE r.WorkCntr = 'Z-Straight'
    AND (r.Status = 'Current' OR r.Status = 'Pending' OR r.Status = 'Future')
    AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '10415%'
    AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '44444%'
    AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '77777%'
    ORDER BY r.JobNo
    ) a
WHERE a.Row > 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to reference the aliased column in the `WHERE` clause does not work because of the logical query processing taking place. The `WHERE` is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause. Therefore, the column `ROW` does not exist when `WHERE` is evaluated.

The correct way to reference the column in this example would be:

```
 select * from (
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.JobNo) AS [Row],
    a.JobNo,
    a.PartNo,
    a.WorkCntr,
    a.StepNo
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT 
      TOP 1000
      r.JobNo,
      r.PartNo,
      r.WorkCntr,
      r.StepNo
      FROM OrderRouting r RIGHT JOIN Scheduling s ON r.JobNo = s.JobNo
      WHERE r.WorkCntr = 'Z-Straight'
      AND (r.Status = 'Current'
      OR r.Status = 'Pending'
      OR r.Status = 'Future')
      AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '10415%'
      AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '44444%'
      AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '77777%'
      ORDER BY r.JobNo
     ) a
    )b
    WHERE b.Row > 10
```

Comment: In case of big amount of data, your query will perform really bad.

Comment: @SouXin Agree, not sure if it is the case. Just focused in explain why it does not work for OP

Answer (score 2):

The column 'Row' is not a part of the Sub-query aliased as 'a'.  Also, you won't be able to use the alias 'Row' in the where clause due to SQL order of operations.

I believe that you can simplify your two queries into a cte:

```
with cte as(
SELECT DISTINCT 
TOP 1000
r.JobNo,
r.PartNo,
r.WorkCntr,
r.StepNo,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.JobNo) AS [Row]
FROM OrderRouting r 
RIGHT JOIN Scheduling s ON r.JobNo = s.JobNo
WHERE r.WorkCntr = 'Z-Straight'
  AND (r.Status IN( 'Current','Pending','Future')
  AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '10415%'
  AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '44444%'
  AND r.JobNo NOT LIKE '77777%') 

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Row > 10
```